# Is this an array initialization?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int ia[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // ia is an array of ten ints
auto ia2(ia); // ia2 is an int* that points to the first element in ia
ia2 = 42;     // error: ia2 is a pointer, and we can't assign an int to a pointer
```

This is a piece of code on C++ Primer. Could someone explain to me what does the second line mean. Is it a way of initialization? Where could I find this kind of initialization? I searched a lot but still couldn't get the relevant information. A link is also welcome. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is copy initialization. For the base types, it is the same as using `=` :

```
int k = 42; 
//is the same as : 
int k(42);
```

This means that line #2 could be rewritten to the following and still have the same meaning :

```
auto ia2 = ia;
```

`auto` will be deducted to an `int*` here.

Comment: Oh,,Thank you! I haven't covered that part. Thanks!:-)